# why static lib build from c++ source target android is very large

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I have a third party SDK source in c++ with CMakelist.txt. When target android the build result .a file's size is 109MB. Meanwhile target Mac .a file is only 19MB.

After strip debug info from the .a file size change to 46MB. Still very large compared by 19MB

Unzip the .a file. The .o file in ELF format is larger than the one in Mach-o format. Is this correct?

Method when build for android

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
    -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK
    -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
    -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang
    -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23
    -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared ..
    make
```

build for mac

```
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g
    -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g/lib
    -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g/include/ ..
    make
```

Comment: My guess it is because you are building towards arm based. Have you tried x86_64 based?

Comment: Don't waste your time building OpenSSL for Android. Just use [ndkports](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/native-dependencies-in-android-studio-40.html)